# Is update.vbe a malicious code?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I found the task "update.vbe" running in my task scheduler, when I checked it's located in "C:\Users\????\AppData\Roaming\origin" and is set to run on logon/

I did some digging and googling around, some folks are saying it's a virus others are saying it's a trojan, but no one seems to be sure.

The file is encrypted so I had to decrypt it and convert it to a vbs in order to examine it and see what's it doing. I know very little vbscript and this is beyond me... can you guys take a look and let us know what the hell is the code doing?

link: http://cha3ab.com/temp/

I tried searching for answers online but nothing is consistent, I guess part of that is due to the fact the it is encrypted and no one bothered to decrypt it and then examine it. I have Avira installed but it couldn't detect it! I also tried Hijackthis and few other scanners from a Hiren BootCD but none flagged it! it's weird but I really think it might be a malicious code! and people seem to be not fully aware of it.

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the maliciousness (or not) of a particular application rather than the process of software development.

Comment: Please note that this is a dup of a question closed on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214651/is-there-a-virus-trojan-in-update-vbe).  The close reason there suggests that this is a 'general computing hardware and software' issue and *might* be appropriate for Super User.  It is not an appropriate question on Programmers.SE (please see our [help/on-topic] for information about what topics we do accept on this Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 3):

It's a virtual currency miner (ie: bitcoin).  They infected you with it to use your computer/electricity to mine coins.

If you look up the web sites named in the constants it's becomes pretty obvious it's not something you want:

- [Norton Safe Web Report](https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show_mobile?name=55900f6043109d0c94f1287fab1ef610.com)
- [virustotal Analysis (http://55900f6043109d0c94f1287fab1ef610.com/)](https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/9af358b0091a0cc8373a015600038ee0c27e76182832c1c0d788b10f896b18da/analysis/)
- [virustotal Analysis (http://b3bd5f983fb3f0f3bfdccaab7bf68644.com/)](https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/b19a197996d9fcebdcab14fe9319aa4f55b36aa3cee1a8006787d1fb3a09bde0/analysis/1407641359/)

Comment: Thanks for the help brother, I actually wouldn't be concerned since I run Tinywall and set it to block everything not whitelisted. Regarding the websites assigned in the constants id, ida and idb, I didn't know how to decrypt them, I wanted to see to whom this code is sending data/info or what ever they're looking for. Thanks again mate