# Firefox eats my CPU as a background process

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cpu

I had big problem with Google Chrome, because it was working in background and eating around 50% CPU *without even opening it or appearing anywhere except the Task Manager. I uninstalled it and installed Firefox, now Firefox acted the same. As you can see in the below image, that background thread of Firefox takes about 30% of my CPU and goes up causing CPU to boost to 3.5GH and heat up, whereas the opened Firefox itself takes 1% and goes down.

My laptop specs:

- Core i 7700HQ

I tried these solutions:

- Chrome was up to date and also Firefox.
- Opened this suspicious process file from Task Manager it redirected me to Firefox installation file.
- Made boot scan and a full scan to my laptop through Avast and nothing found.
- When I installed Firefox I didn't install any extensions, but the problem exists somewhere though.
- I installed Opera and this problem doesn't exist anymore, but I want to know what was the matter with Google Chrome and Firefox.

[image: high usage]

Comment: Get [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and provide a screenshot of the stack of the *thread* that’s using the CPU in this Firefox process.

Comment: Opera probably works because it's less susceptive to browser injections. Do a system-wide anti-malware and anti-spyware scan and see if anything is found. Either that or your core i7 is a dual core celeron.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 i made sure that option in Chrome is disabled, but it kept working on background though.

Comment: @DanielB i will reinstall chrome and try using process explorer to get that _stake thread_

Comment: @dsstorefile1  it's probably a malware as you said i will make malware scan, maybe my lap got infected from cracked games D:: .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @dsstorefile1 denoted in comments above there were a malware that were use my cpu to mine coins.
I used malwarebyte to make a full scan and it found this 
*Trojan.Agent.VBS* that lies in **C:\USERS\??\APPDATA\ROAMING\LIBRARIES\ MicrosoftRuntimeUpdate.vbe**
and it's a malware as denoted here [here](https://superuser.com/a/794861)